# Contradictory assembly versions in use from msbuild

Tags: .net, msbuild, mono, .net-assembly, gac

I am using msbuild v. 15 as included with mono on Ubuntu. I had downgraded my assembly references from gtk-sharp 3.0 to 2.12 to accommodate incompatibility with monodevelop's stetic designer. Unfortunately, msbuild still (for some reason) wants to use the newer version. Verbose output of the build shows (excerpts only):

```
Task "GetDependsOnNETStandard" skipped, due to false condition;
 ('$(DependsOnNETStandard)' == '' AND '$(NETStandardInbox)' != 'true' AND 
 '@(_CandidateNETStandardReferences)' != '') 
 was evaluated as ('' == '' AND 'true' != 'true' AND 
 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089;
 gtk-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f;
 gdk-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f;
 glib-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f;
 atk-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f;
 Mono.Cairo, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756;
 ...' != '').


Task "ResolveAssemblyReference"
  TargetFrameworkMoniker:
      .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1
  TargetFrameworkMonikerDisplayName:
      .NET Framework 4.7.1
  TargetedRuntimeVersion:
      v4.0.30319
  Assemblies:
      System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
      gtk-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f
      gdk-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f
      glib-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f
      atk-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f
      Mono.Cairo, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756
      ...

Primary reference "gtk-sharp, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f".
  Resolved file path is "/usr/lib/mono/gac/gtk-sharp/3.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gtk-sharp.dll".
  Reference found at search path location "{GAC}".
      For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
      Considered "/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETFramework/v4.7.1/gtk-sharp.winmd", but it didn't exist.
      Considered "/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETFramework/v4.7.1/gtk-sharp.dll", but it didn't exist.
      Considered "/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETFramework/v4.7.1/gtk-sharp.exe", but it didn't exist.
      Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.7.1-api/gtk-sharp.winmd", but it didn't exist.
      Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.7.1-api/gtk-sharp.dll", but it didn't exist.
      Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.7.1-api/gtk-sharp.exe", but it didn't exist.
      Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.7.1-api/Facades/gtk-sharp.winmd", but it didn't exist.
      Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.7.1-api/Facades/gtk-sharp.dll", but it didn't exist.
      Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.7.1-api/Facades/gtk-sharp.exe", but it didn't exist.
      Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.7.1-api/Facades/gtk-sharp.winmd", but it didn't exist.
      Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.7.1-api/Facades/gtk-sharp.dll", but it didn't exist.
      Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.7.1-api/Facades/gtk-sharp.exe", but it didn't exist.
  Found related file "/usr/lib/mono/gac/gtk-sharp/3.0.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gtk-sharp.dll.config".
  This reference is not "CopyLocal" because it's registered in the GAC.
  The ImageRuntimeVersion for this reference is "".
```

I'm unclear on why it switches from 2.12 to 3.0 halfway through the build.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to diagnose why exactly the unified reference ended up at a higher than expected version of the assembly from the information you provided, but here are two pointers that I found invaluable in resolving similar problems.

1. The [MSBuild binlog viewer](http://msbuildlog.com/) tool ([source](https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/MSBuildStructuredLog)). Add `-bl:somename.binlog` to MSBuild invocation, and then examine the log with the tool. The log file is self-contained (includes zipped scripts and everything) and can be viewed on another machine. I never used it except on Windows, so cannot tell if it works under Mono.
2. [The most detailed explanation of the assembly unification process](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/50639058f/documentation/wiki/ResolveAssemblyReference.md) during build from one of the MSBuild top designers, Rainer Sigwald. The `ResolveAssemblyReference` is probably one of the most logically complex steps in the build, and this reference literally covers it all.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `lib{atk,gdk,glib,gtk}3.0-cil` packages fixed my build. This makes no sense, but it worked.